# AngularJS pass service variable to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I built a simple app with user authentication base on this: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En)

Basically, I have a userAccountService, responsible for communicating with server and login controller handling the login process.

From other controller I want to check if user is already logged in (to hide LogIn button, and show user profile instead).

So I have a navController

```
function navCtrl ($scope, $modal, userAccountService) {

    $scope.IsUserLoggedIn = function () {
        return userAccountService.isUserLoggedIn;
    } 

}
```

So in HTML I use this `ng-hide="isUserLoggedIn()`

my userAccountService:

```
app.factory('userAccountService', ['$http', '$q', userAccountService]);

function userAccountService($http, $q) {

    var service = {
        registerUser: registerUser,
        loginUser: loginUser,
        logOut: logOut,
        getValues: getValues,
        isUserLoggedIn: false,
        accessToken: ""
    };

    // code ommited
    function loginUser(userData) {
        var tokenUrl = serverBaseUrl + "/Token";
        if (!userData.grant_type) {
           userData.grant_type = "password";
        }

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: tokenUrl,
            data: userData,
        })
            .success(function (data,status,headers,cfg) {
                // save the access_token as this is required for each API call. 
                accessToken = data.access_token;
                isUserLoggedIn = true;
                // check the log screen to know currently back from the server when a user log in successfully.
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })

            .error(function (err, status) {
                console.log(err);
                deferred.reject(status);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Here's another interesting read I took inspiration from: [link](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app)

Comment: We don't know what you're doing wrong, because you didn't tell us what your problem is.   What behavior are you expecting? What is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a variable, but you can return a function, so create a function that returns that variable.

Try something like this, it returns your service object (you might want to put a $watch on it):

Service

```
function userAccountService($http, $q) {

  function getData() {
      return service;
  }
  ...
}
```

Controller

```
$scope.IsUserLoggedIn = userAccountService.getData().isUserLoggedIn;
```

---

Also, you're not correctly updating the state variable from your success callback - you're creating global variables instead of using the service object properties. So, for example:

```
isUserLoggedIn = true;
```

should be:

```
service.isUserLoggedIn = true;
```

Comment: Still doesn't work - I put `console.log(service)` to $http.success in loginUser - isUserLoggedIn is set to true. I put getData function and in my controller the same line as You wrote here.

Comment: And, what happens? I'm not sure I was able to catch all you wrote.

Comment: The service object printed to console has property `isUserLoggedIn: true`, but in my nav controller, `$scope.IsUserLoggedIn = userAccoutnService.getData().isUserLoggedIn` is still false. I added console.log() do getData() function, it seems it's never called.

Comment: Any chance you could replicate it in jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: Great, you're going to laugh. `IsUserLoggedIn` is not the same as `isUserLoggedIn` :) See: http://plnkr.co/edit/XJWGC30OWsToPquWpgHK?p=preview

Comment: Note that I'm also updating the $scope.IsUserLoggedIn inside of your login function... Which is ok, I guess, but you can use $watch there if you wish.